# Calling a function to control a confirm alert from within an if statement

Tags: php, javascript, confirm

Good evening .. 
I have a form where you assign work to a worker, however, if that work is already assigned then user has a choice of either reassigning it or returning to previous page.
so I'm trying to write the syntax for a confirm alert that redirects user to one page or another depending on his choice ,
I placed it within the head section and it goes something like this:

```
function show_confirm() {
    var con = confirm("Already assigned.. would you like to reassign?");
    if (con ==true) {
       window.location = "reassign.php"
    } else {
       window.location = "index.php"
    }
 }
```

The question is : how do you call this function depending on an if statement? I have seen some examples on the internet where people place the function (rather than just call it ) directly inside the if statement, but wouldn't that be mixing different kinds of script? 
So .. how do you call the function from within this if statement?
I tried this but it didnt work:

```
$flat=$_POST['flat'];
$check= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignment WHERE flat = '$flat'");
$num= mysql_num_rows($check);
if ($num!=0) {   show_confirm();
 } else { //irrellivant code
```

Comment: You're trying to call a JavaScript function in your PHP code. That's not going to work like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a JavaScript function, you just place the function itself inside the header, and then in PHP, you output the call to the function in your if like this:

```
if ($num!=0) {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">show_confirm();</script>';
} else { 
   //irrelevant code
}
```

PHP is a server-side scripting language, while JavaScript is client-side. You can't call the JavaScript function directly from the server-side like you were trying to do. You can however output javascript to the page via PHP as I have done in my example.

Comment: that didnt work either .. actually i did try it before posting the question too .. i tried it again now but nothing.

Comment: It should work if it's getting outputted in the correct place on the page, are you outputting it in the body of the HTML page?

Comment: OK .. it did work ..it was a silly typo ( as usual ) .. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to mix php (server side) and javascript (client side) in one process which won't work.

When you submit the form to check if they are already assigned you then need to redirect them to a confirm page, from there you would have yes/no buttons linking to the reassign and go back pages.

The best solution would actually be to handle this with AJAX but given the nature question I think its best to stick with non-ajax workflow.

Let me know if that makes sense, if not I will add some more detail

Comment: what you are suggesting is creating an extra page to confirm the request i know how to do that ., but im trying to do that thru an alert instead ... is that not possible?

Comment: Its certainly possible, just more complicated. You need to look into ajax, which will enable you to fire off a request to your php script, the one that works out if a user is already assigned and then display an alert http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is a good place to start.

Comment: ok .. that would take alot of learning tho .. ok ..question: how come it works when u call the function in places like : onclick="function()" inside a button tag?